# How to create a alert message for existing child node data in php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I have a xml document:

```
<root>
   <info>
      <name>John</name>
      <address>USA</address>
   </info>
   <info>
      <name>David</name>
      <address>Australia</address>
   </info>
</root>
```

I need to check the names; if the name John exists in the `<name>` node then it should show alert that the name already exists, and if not exists the data should append in the XML document.

Any help..?

Comment: The best way to get an answer is to try something yourself and post the code and your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
$Entry = $xml->channel->item;

foreach ($Entry as $EntryItem){
    if($EntryItem->name == 'ArrayList/Whatever') {
        echo "ignoring $EntryItem->name";
    } else {
        // Whatever code
    }
}
```

Thats most likely a start of what you'd need to be doing. I'm not too sure where you're getting your list of names or how you want to be alerted of such, based off of that php can not give an alert box but javascript can. You can use javascript after to check for information for maybe a hidden list then alert that way. Theres far too many ways of doing so.